# jquery click() event on <a> with id having certain prefix not firing the alert() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to set up a function that will listen for when an `<a>` tag that has an id value with a certain prefix and then do something. Here's what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#mytable").DataTable();

  $('a[id |= "food"]').click(function() {
    alert("A food link was clicked!");
    });
  
 });
```

```css
.some-class {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<div>
  <table id = "mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id = "food-1" class = "some-class" href = "#">Bacon</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id = "food-2" class = "some-class" href = "#">Pancakes</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a id = "drink-1" class = "some-class" href = "#">Beer</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

For some reason, in the snippet here, it works perfectly as expected. However, in my browser (both Firefox 43.0.3 and Chrome 47.0.2526.111), there is no response. I know it's bad form to ask a question about an issue that isn't reproducible, but I'm hoping someone knows what might be preventing this function from running. There are no errors and all of my other javascript/jquery functions run. Even reducing my jquery function `$("a").click(function()...)` doesn't work. It just seems like it's not recognizing the fact that a link is being clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

I've been doing various things trying to figure out why JQuery isn't triggering the alert when the link is clicked, but it seems that JQuery can't really interact with the DataTable at all. The following code had no effect on the table.

`$("#mytable").find("tr").css("background-color", "#000");`

And the following code produces an object of length 0:

`$("#mytable").children();`

I'm at a total loss as to why JQuery is having such a hard time interacting with the `DataTable`.

Comment: What if you update the selector as follows: `$('a[id^="food"]')`?

Comment: it worked for me, are you putting the document ready at the end of the file?

Comment: @BenM: The OP's selector is valid: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta Can you elaborate please? I'm relatively new to HTML/JS/JQuery, so I don't have a firm grasp on what the "order" of things should be. As it stands, my javascript is a saved in a file called "main.js", which is pulled in in the header of the html.

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta doesn't matter where `document.ready` gets called...  the callback still fires when dom content is loaded

Comment: @brittenb don't worry about order as long as jQuery.js loads in the page before your code

Comment: If you put a break-point on the `$('a[id |= "food"]').click(function() {` line, is the break-point hit? What elements do you see in `$('a[id |= "food"]')`?

Comment: use document ready after include jquery

Comment: @whistling_marmot when I run `console.log($('a[id = ...)` I get `Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → 127.0.0.1:4849, selector: "a[id |= "food"]" }`. So it's apparently not finding anything.

Comment: @brittenb
go to this snippet, copy the content and save as stackoverflow.html then open it in a browser http://pastebin.com/RbTLmuWQ

Comment: use the render events within datatable api if you want to affect specific rows. You aren't in control of how the plugin manipulates the dom...so work from within the methods it exposes

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, that was the problem. I'm not actually building the DataTables structure, it's being done in R and then fed to JSON, which in turn is being fed to DataTables. By embedding a callback function in the `dataTable` call, I was able to manipulate the table and not the DOM. Thanks for the help, truly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

jQuery DataTables manipulates DOM for various reasons, therefore event handlers attached directly will work for first page only.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call, see example below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#mytable").DataTable();

   $('#mytable').on('click', 'a[id|="food"]', function(){
      alert("A food link was clicked!");
   }); 
});
```

From jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcjsm8xx/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I feel like these answers make total sense, and should work, but they're not. When I run `console.log($("#mytable a"));` it returns an object with length 0. So it's not finding the links inside of my table at all. But if I change the `href` of the links and click on one, it redirects to me where I should go. Is there a reason why DataTables would in any way mask the presence of an element?

Comment: @brittenb, are you loading data via Ajax request or in HTML? If you're loading data via Ajax request, you need to attach event handlers in [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) callback.

Comment: No, I'm loading my data as HTML/Javascript. To the best of my knowledge, there is no Ajax interaction.

Comment: @brittenb, added an example to demonstrate that my solution works.

Comment: Thank you! I've been doing some digging around and it has to deal with pre- and post-initialisation of the `DataTable`, which you mentioned earlier. There were some mitigating circumstances on my end (details I left out because I thought they were irrelevant, but were not) that were getting in the way. Everything has worked out now, thanks to you. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since `dataTables` plugin manipulates the html in the page your issue is likely that you will need to use ***event delegation***

When elements are removed from the page and replaced with the same html....any event listeners that were attached are lost

Also ID's shouldn't be repeated so change them to class instead

Try

```js
$('#mytable').on('click', 'a.food', function(){
    alert("A food link was clicked!");
});
```

Comment: true, but this will be a future answer :D, he only has 3 items, the delegation its needed when the table paginate results

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta not when table gets default sort set

Comment: @gyrocode.com thx... spaced out a bit in my copy/paste then edit